# Login form in same url as web application

Tags: php, html, web, authentication

On my server I have two folders. One is for login system (login, registration, forget password etc.) and second is for web application that i am developing. Both folders have index.php. 
I want that when the user visit my site (mydomain.com), he must logged in to be allowed to use the application. I need to stay on url mydomain.com.  Not **mydomian.com/app**.

I was thinking about moving the applications files in the www/ folder and load the login form with iframe, but in my opinion it is not the right solution.

For example, Instagram.com has exactly what I want. You must login to see photos, but you stays on the instagram.com

Comment: I think, if we should take the example of _Instagram_, they check for the `session()` state of the user, and verify if he is logged in. Depending of the case, a different page is shown, but all the code is located in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use include() by checking if user is logged in

```
if($loggedin)
    include("/app/index.php");
else
    include("usercontrol/index.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not using a framework, you could easily achieve that wit routing on any framework. Not using a frameworks you can include different php logic on your main index file depending on the session status